# Can I call another overloaded constructor in C++?

Tags: c++, overloading

```
class draw
{
    draw(circle i)
    {
        // draw a circle;
    }

    draw(circle i, circle j)
    {
        draw(i);
        draw(j);
    }
}
```

Can I call another overloaded constructor of the same class in C++ even if using template?

Answer (score 2):

No, in C++ you cannot have one constructor directly call another (well, at least not more than once). However, you can have each constructor call a third method that performs actual work.

```
class draw
{
    draw(circle i)
    {
        do_draw(i);
    }

    draw(circle i, circle j)
    {
        do_draw(i);
        do_draw(j);
    }

    void do_draw(circle c)
    {
        // draw a circle;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well didn't c++11 (or at least c++14) introduced calling other constructors in the member initializer list?

Comment: Yes, C++11 allows a constructor to call another constructor of the same class in the initializer list.  It is called [delegating constructors](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#delegating-ctor).

Comment: That's right, but you can only call a delegated constructor once, not more than once as this question suggests.

Comment: @GregHewgill How the question suggests, that the constructor should be called _more than once_? Can you elaborate about an actually applicable solution regarding the current standard please?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: What? I'm not talking about any standard. I'm observing that the OP's two-argument constructor actually wants to draw two circles. If there is a single-argument constructor that draws one circle, you can't call that constructor twice to draw two different circles. One would have to create a third method as I have suggested in my answer.